# Is there an equivalent of "stay" for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, multiple-monitors

On my laptop at work, I use an external monitor, but when I'm away from my desk I just use the laptop monitor.

On OSX I used to use [Stay](http://cordlessdog.com/stay/) but I'm struggling to get the same functionality on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

[**Compiz Place Windows Plugin**](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Place) may be useful for you but not essentially the same as "Stay" for OSX. Anyway, there are a few [other plugins](http://wiki.compiz.org/) that will allow you to have more control on the position, placement mode and other window features.

From the site:

> The Place Windows plugin provides some basic window placement
>   algorithms, to place windows at a natural and sensible place when
>   created.

and

> **Window Placement Rules**
>
> Finally, the place plugin allows you to place matched windows on a
>   certain area of the screen, or a certain viewport every time.

A screenshot is provided here for you to see the "Fixed Window Placement" tab inside of the Place Windows Plugin.

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: You're right, the Place Windows plugin isn't quite what I want, and while there are a few plugins that move windows etc, there's none that remember where they were based on which monitor is attached.

Comment: Weird case that yours. Since my Place Windows Plugin is doing a great work on my dual monitor setup. All that I did was to let know the plugin on which coordinates will my windows be placed using a "x, y" styled reference. In the extended desktop, the windows will go to the given coordinates each time they are opened. I don't know how are you using your desktop configuration but this is working pretty fine for me.

Comment: I'm not bothered about when the window opens, it's when I attach or detach a monitor. When I'm on the laptop alone, it doesn't matter, there is only 1 screen, but when I attach a monitor, I want some windows to move automatically to the new screen.