# Is there a way to 'sleep' browser windows with tabs I'm not currently reading?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, evince, top, nice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an equivalent of “stay” for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95983/is-there-an-equivalent-of-stay-for-ubuntu)

I typically have a lot of PDF's open while I'm computing. Many of them are "I'll read this later" rather than "I expect to be able to immediately switch to this `evince` window".

I don't understand how Ubuntu handles memory in a deep way, but it seems like these `evince` instances are eating up memory when they don't need to. I would be happy if the OS held the PDF open in somewhere other than RAM. I imagine this is what the `bg` or `ctrl+Z` command does?

That's enough background on my understanding of the question I'm about to ask. Here it is:

Is there a way to 'sleep' PDF's, browser windows, or other stuff I'm reading so that the rest of my system will speed up?

Comment: no, bg does not make your programs not eat up ram.  For instance if you typed `google-chrome` and you decided you wanted to use your terminal or close it instead of being tied up with google chrome, you type ^Z, then google-chrome is "stopped." Then type `bg 1` [Assuming you don't have any other running processes from that term, otherwise you would need 2, 3, or etc], and it puts job 1, `google-chrome`, that you stopped, back to running, and in the background.  That is the long way of just typing `google-chrome&`

Comment: @Matt, could I `ctrl+Z` an Evince window and the process would use up less RAM?

Comment: I believe that is false.  Ctrl+Z just gives the STOP signal. [same as `kill -STOP 9999` I believe].  Now, once you press Ctrl+Z, you will notice Evince freezes up.  Because the process is no longer processing. [lol] when you continue it [Either with `kill -CONT 9999`, or `fg 1`] it resumes where it left off.  So it cannot free up ram because your program didn't lose any data by stopping and resuming the process.